# Roslyn GetDescriptionAsync gives incomplete description

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslynpad

I am trying to explore Roslyn's code completion service. I am able to get the completion list, but when I try to get the description it only returns the type and access modifiers, but not the actual description (e.g. Function used for printing to the console).

This is how I tried getting the description:

```
 var code = @"using System;
            using TestDll;

            public class MyClass
            {
                public static void MyMethod(int value)
                {
                    Test.
                }
            }";

            var projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(), "MyProject", "MyProject", LanguageNames.CSharp).
                WithMetadataReferences(new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile("TestDll.dll", documentation: XmlDocumentationProvider.CreateFromFile("TestDLL.xml")) });
            var project = workspace.AddProject(projectInfo);
            var document = workspace.AddDocument(project.Id, "MyFile.cs", SourceText.From(code));

            await PrintCompletionResults(document, code.LastIndexOf("Test.") + 5);
```

PrintCompletion Method

```
 private static async Task PrintCompletionResults(Document document, int position)
        {
            var completionService = CompletionService.GetService(document);
            var results = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(document, position);

            foreach (var i in results.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.DisplayText);
                var desc = completionService.GetDescriptionAsync(document, i).Result; // returns for example "interface Test.DebugPrint()"

                Console.WriteLine(desc.Text);
                foreach (var prop in i.Properties)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{prop.Key}:{prop.Value}  ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                foreach (var tag in i.Tags)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{tag}  ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem here -- you may have to drop breakpoints into XmlDocumentationProvider to see if it's actually being called internally.